# Using Hadoop in IoT domain - Smart Street Lighting Systems

Tags: hadoop, iot

I think I have come up with a project idea and I need some help in evaluating it.

Title: **Smart Grid System with energy saving function**

Time series data refers to the data recorded over a period of time and can be generated by an equipment and collected by sensors in IOT.
Example:

```
daily air temperature or monthly precipitation in a specific location.
```

[Click here to see a SMART GRID SYSTEM](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/fig2_261479865)

In case of Smart Grid System shown above,the time series data can be generated by the sensor unit and that data can be collected by the sensor in the nearby smart street light.

For instance, when a person comes near a sensor unit and not near the street light, it will trigger the sensor unit which in turn will make the sensor unit to generate time series data which will be instantaneously be delivered to the sensors present in street light and street lights will turn on immediately and hence won’t need to turn on when the person comes right in front of it, which is actually meaningful.

Here we can take the time series data to be the distance between the object or person approaching and the sensor in the street light let us say ‘d’.
The methodology is whenever the distance ‘d’ is less than the cutoff distance ‘x’ ie the desired distance within which we want the lights to get turned on,the sensor will switch the light on and whenever the distance becomes(because we have been observing the distance over a period of time as it is a time series data) greater than ‘x’ sensors should turn off the light.

There are basically three ways to process the time series data:

1. Use of Relational Database
2. Use of Real-time Database
3. Use of Hadoop(HBase)

We generally go for the third approach to process the time series data because the first two approaches have many disadvantages.

Now the issue is that, how am I to do the simulation for this? I have read about Hadoop and its use in building IoT Architectures but how do I incorporate the use of Hadoop to this idea?

What else do I need to be able to complete this project?

Current Skill set: Proficient in Python/Opencv, Basic DL. 
Any help in improving my question and how can I take this project further is appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place to discuss projects ideas. It is for getting help on *specific* problem in programming.

Comment: Alright, Could you let me know of a platform where I can perhaps get some valuable output?

Comment: The question is very broad and the choice of technologies depends on a lot of criteria, so you cannot get a definitive solution here. In general, you can have iot devices send data to scalable message broker like apache Kafka or active mq. On the broker you can have multiple consumers that can do live or batch processing. Simple thing is to store the data to a scalable database (nosql database that fits your need) and then perform batch processing and queries on that database to present the data to the final user.

Comment: For sensor data, you can use projects like MiNiFi or MQTT, which send data to aggregators running collection servers like Apache NiFi, which then could produce into Kafka for collection and distribution to other services (including Python), but typically some real-time database